# Flutter: GetX navigation with MultiProvider does not work

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-provider

I am using Provider for State management and GetX for navigation in my App.

I am navigating to a new page like this:

```
await Get.to(
  () => MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: languageModel,
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: authenticationModel,
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => SavedArticleModel(),
      ),
    ],
    child: const SavedArticlePage(),
  ),
);
```

This works fine, but when I try to navigate from SavedArticlePage to a different page, nothing happens.

The same code works as intended when using the navigator:

```
await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: languageModel,
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: authenticationModel,
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => SavedArticleModel(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const SavedArticlePage(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: But why are you using Getx for navigation in place of Navigator?

Comment: Navigator is the inbuilt class provided by Flutter and you should use that not any 3rd party packages in your app.